# Can you update a genesis configuration via forkless upgrade?

Tags: polkadot, runtime-upgrade

If I have a substrate based blockchain live with a genesis configuration & it also is included a parachain in Polkadot. Now if I want to do a forkless upgrade to the chain, is it possible to update the constants in the genesis config?

For example, if I had added polkadot.js wallet address as a special account that holds some fund in the genesis and now want to change it to a different wallet address with a forkless upgrade, is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The genesis file/state can't be changed, it is what all the peers use to verify the chain (really simplified explanation), it is what it initialize the chain (thus the name genesis). Keep in mind that it is from the genesis state that all the rest of the chain history is constructed, if we would be able to change it, we would basically alter all the block after the initialization.

However if you want to change variable after the launch of the chain it is possible, you will have to perform storage migration.
See the [Substrate migration doc](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/parachains/runtime-upgrade/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.